# Azure WebJobs: difference between Console.WriteLine and logger.WriteLine

Tags: azure, logging, azure-webjobs

The method of webjob can have `TextWriter logger` as parameter. But if I call:

```
logger.WriteLine("Test");
Console.WriteLine("Test");
```

it does the same. Just write "INFO" record to console and logfile.

What is difference between them and what sense to have `TextWriter logger` as parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it does the same. Just write "INFO" record to console and logfile.

Yes, they all could achieve the above function in web job. You can use any of them in web job. Just the official definition has slightly different. And the TextWriter logger parameter is optional in method.